# How can i find an Object key with the longest char length in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

Say i have a collection of objects like so

```
var collection = [
{
     name:"John",
     age:12,
     location:"Califonia",
     gender:"Male"
},
{
     name:"Jane",
     age:18,
     location:"New york",
     gender:"Female"
}
]
```

it is obvious `"location"` is the object key with the longest character length.

But how can i get this dynamically as i dont know how collection will be structured in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are sure the items in the collection will always have the same structure you can simple do this.

```
var collection = [
{
     name:"John",
     age:12,
     location:"Califonia",
     gender:"Male"
},
{
     name:"Jane",
     age:18,
     location:"New york",
     gender:"Female"
}
]

function getMaxKeys(collection){
        var keys = Object.keys(collection[0]);
        var keyWithMaxWidth = keys.reduce(function(prev, current){
            if(prev.length > current.length) return prev;
            else return current
        });
        return keyWithMaxWidth;
}

getMaxKeys(collection) //location
```

Answer (score 1):

With these functions:

```
/**
 * Get the longest key in an object.
 */ 
function longestKey(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(all, current) {
    return all.length > current.length ? all : current;
  });
}

/**
 * Get the object with the longest key from array of objects.
 */ 
function longestKeyObj(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(all, current) {
    return longestKey(all).length > longestKey(current).length ? all : current;
  });
}
```

You can do:

```
const me = {
  name: 'nabil',
  occupation: 'programming',
  dob: '1984-12-28',
};

const you = {
  longestKey: 'blah!',
};

console.log('The object is: ', longestKeyObj([me, you]));
console.log('The key is: ', longestKey(longestKeyObj([me, you])));
```

Which outputs:

> The object is:  { longestKey: 'blah!' }
>
> The key is:  longestKey

Demo: https://repl.it/@kadimi/longestKey

Answer (score 0):

you can get array object key of specific object by  command :

```
Object.keys(<object>)
```

Make a loop for find longest key. In your problem you need loop for all object in array

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the keys with `Object.keys(obj)` and pick up the longest one, Use the following function:

```
var getLongestKey = function getLongestKey(obj) {
  for (key in keys) {
    if (keys[key].length > longest.length) {
      longest = keys[key];
    }
  }
}
```

And this is a working demo, to get the longest key for all the objects in the array :

```js
var collection = [{
  name: "John",
  age: 12,
  location: "Califonia",
  gender: "Male"
}, {
  name: "Jane",
  age: 18,
  location: "New york",
  gender: "Female"
}];


var getLongestKey = function getLongestKey(obj) {

  for (key in keys) {
    if (keys[key].length > longest.length) {
      longest = keys[key];
    }
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {

  var obj = collection[i];
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var longest = keys[0];
  getLongestKey(obj);
  alert("Longest key in Object " + i + " is : " + longest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will solve your problem in optimal way:

```javascript
var sorted = (Object.keys(collection[0])).sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
});
sorted[0]; // Location
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop each object in the array and then loop each property in the object like so:

```
var collection = [
    {
         name:"John",
         age:12,
         location:"Califonia",
         gender:"Male"
    },
    {
         name:"Jane",
         age:18,
         location:"New york",
         gender:"Female"
    },
    {
        veryLong: "This key will definitely be the longest"
    }
];

var stats = {
    key: '',
    valLen: 0
};
collection.forEach(function(obj){
    for(var prop in obj){
        if(obj[prop].length > stats.valLen){
            stats.key = prop
            stats.valLen = obj[prop].length
        }
    }
});

console.log(stats.key);
console.log(stats.valLen);
```

Each item in the array may have a different format.
This example will log: 'veryLong' as longest key and 39 as its length.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdfkmkfk/)